# accessing nested json api data in angular using model

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am new to json and angular. I am trying to access an API response using model. But it is giving me undefined when I try to access it.

Below is the json API returns

```
{
     "Inventory App": {
         "AnalyticsUI": "UP",
         "BaseUI": "UP",
         "PlanningUI": "UP",
         "UploadUI": "DOWN"
     }
}
```

My model definition is below

```
export class AppModel {
constructor(
        public experience: AppList
    ) {}
}

export class AppList {
    constructor(
        public appName1: String,
        public appName2: String,
        public appName3: String,
        public appName4: String,
        public appName5: String
    ) {}
}
```

Below is my service call

```
import { AppModel } from './model/appList.model';
 getAppStatus$(): Observable<AppModel> {
            return this.http
              .get('https://abc.xyc.com/AppController/AppsStatus')
              .catch(this._handleError);
          }
```

Below is the component where I am trying to access the API data.

```
export class MainComponent {
......
appList: AppModel;
.....

public _getAppStatus() {
        this.appSub = this.api
            .getAppStatus$()
            .subscribe(
            res => {
                this.appList = res;
                console.log(this.appList);
                console.log(this.appList.experience);
            },
            err => {console.error(err); }
            );
    }
}
```

It is giving me undefined when I try to access this.appList.experience. Where as this.appList is printing the json result properly.  Any help on this is much appreciated.

Console output :
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXDFF.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the output of console.log(this.appList)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXDFF.jpg

Comment: have you tried initialize appList? something like this: `appList: AppModel = new AppModel();`

Comment: Your problem is from the image you just showed me that your object does not contain a experience. Assuming the first one is actually what i asked you to provide

Comment: Should the Api key name match the model names ? For example API returns a key "AnalyticsUI" . Should I declare as AnalyticsUI: string in my model or can I declare XYXS: string ?

Comment: Your property names need to match. Angular cannot automagically read your mind ;)

Comment: Thanks AJT. Got it now.

Answer (score 0):

As AJT and Khan stated, issue was property name not matching. Once I changed the property name to match the json response, I was able to get the values.